# Nginx Ingress not working on k3s running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, k3s, home-assistant, ingress-nginx

I have k3s installed on 4 Raspberry Pi's with traefik disabled.
I'm trying to run Home assistant on it using Nginx Ingress controller, `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.3.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`.

But for some reason, I just cannot expose the service. The ingress assigned 192.168.0.57, which is one of the nodes' IP. Am I missing something?

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl get ingress -n home-assistant home-assistant-ingress 
NAME                     CLASS   HOSTS        ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
home-assistant-ingress   nginx   smart.home   192.168.0.57   80      20h
root@rpi1:~# curl http://192.168.0.57/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.57 port 80: Connection refused
root@rpi1:~# curl http://smart.home/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to smart.home port 80: Connection refused
```

Please see following.

Pod:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl describe pod -n home-assistant home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679-zbwn7 
Name:         home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679-zbwn7
Namespace:    home-assistant
Priority:     0
Node:         rpi4/192.168.0.58
Start Time:   Tue, 16 Aug 2022 20:31:28 +0100
Labels:       app=home-assistant
              pod-template-hash=7c4674b679
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.3.7
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.3.7
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679
Containers:
  home-assistant:
    Container ID:   containerd://c7ec189112e9f2d085bd7f9cc7c8086d09b312e30771d7d1fef424685fcfbd07
    Image:          ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable
    Image ID:       ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant@sha256:0555dc6a69293a1a700420224ce8d03048afd845465f836ef6ad60f5763b44f2
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 17 Aug 2022 18:06:16 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Tue, 16 Aug 2022 20:33:33 +0100
      Finished:     Wed, 17 Aug 2022 18:06:12 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n5tb7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-n5tb7:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From     Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----     -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  43m   kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Pulled          43m   kubelet  Container image "ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable" already present on machine
  Normal  Created         43m   kubelet  Created container home-assistant
  Normal  Started         43m   kubelet  Started container home-assistant
```

The pod is listening at port 8123

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl exec -it -n home-assistant home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679-zbwn7 -- netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      60/python3          
tcp6       0      0 :::8123                 :::*                    LISTEN      60/python3
```

Deployment:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl describe deployments.apps -n home-assistant 
Name:                   home-assistant-deploy
Namespace:              home-assistant
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 16 Aug 2022 20:31:28 +0100
Labels:                 app=home-assistant
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=home-assistant
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=home-assistant
  Containers:
   home-assistant:
    Image:        ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Service with port set to 8080 and target port to 8123:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl describe svc -n home-assistant home-assistant-service 
Name:                     home-assistant-service
Namespace:                home-assistant
Labels:                   app=home-assistant
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=home-assistant
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.248.75
IPs:                      10.43.248.75
LoadBalancer Ingress:     192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56, 192.168.0.57, 192.168.0.58
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8123/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31678/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.3.7:8123
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                 From           Message
  ----    ------            ----                ----           -------
  Normal  UpdatedIngressIP  20h                 svccontroller  LoadBalancer Ingress IP addresses updated: 192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56, 192.168.0.58
  Normal  UpdatedIngressIP  20h (x2 over 22h)   svccontroller  LoadBalancer Ingress IP addresses updated: 192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56, 192.168.0.57, 192.168.0.58
  Normal  AppliedDaemonSet  20h (x19 over 22h)  svccontroller  Applied LoadBalancer DaemonSet kube-system/svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711
  Normal  UpdatedIngressIP  47m                 svccontroller  LoadBalancer Ingress IP addresses updated: 192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56
  Normal  UpdatedIngressIP  47m                 svccontroller  LoadBalancer Ingress IP addresses updated: 192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56, 192.168.0.57
  Normal  UpdatedIngressIP  47m                 svccontroller  LoadBalancer Ingress IP addresses updated: 192.168.0.53, 192.168.0.56, 192.168.0.57, 192.168.0.58
  Normal  AppliedDaemonSet  47m (x8 over 47m)   svccontroller  Applied LoadBalancer DaemonSet kube-system/svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711
```

My Ingress:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl describe ingress -n home-assistant home-assistant-ingress 
Name:             home-assistant-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        home-assistant
Address:          192.168.0.57
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  smart.home  
              /   home-assistant-service:8080 (10.42.3.7:8123)
Annotations:  <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    19h (x2 over 19h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    49m (x3 over 50m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync

root@rpi1:~# kubectl get ingress -n home-assistant home-assistant-ingress 
NAME                     CLASS   HOSTS        ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
home-assistant-ingress   nginx   smart.home   192.168.0.57   80      19h
```

Can confirm I have Nginx ingress controller running:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl get pod -n ingress-nginx 
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-2thj7        0/1     Completed   0             22h
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-kwm4m         0/1     Completed   1             22h
ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt   1/1     Running     2 (52m ago)   22h
```

Ingress Nginx Controller log

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.3.0
  Build:         2b7b74854d90ad9b4b96a5011b9e8b67d20bfb8f
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.10

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0818 06:51:52.008386       7 client_config.go:617] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0818 06:51:52.009962       7 main.go:230] "Creating API client" host="https://10.43.0.1:443"
I0818 06:51:52.123762       7 main.go:274] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="24" git="v1.24.3+k3s1" state="clean" commit="990ba0e88c90f8ed8b50e0ccd375937b841b176e" platform="linux/arm64"
I0818 06:51:52.594773       7 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0818 06:51:52.691571       7 ssl.go:531] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0818 06:51:52.773089       7 nginx.go:258] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0818 06:51:52.807863       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"21ae6485-bb0e-447e-b098-c510e43b171e", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"934", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0818 06:51:53.912887       7 store.go:429] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="home-assistant/home-assistant-ingress" ingressclass="nginx"
I0818 06:51:53.913414       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"home-assistant", Name:"home-assistant-ingress", UID:"eeb12441-9cd4-4571-b0da-5b2978ff3267", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"8719", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0818 06:51:53.975141       7 nginx.go:301] "Starting NGINX process"
I0818 06:51:53.975663       7 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
I0818 06:51:53.976173       7 nginx.go:321] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0818 06:51:53.980492       7 controller.go:167] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0818 06:51:54.025524       7 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader
I0818 06:51:54.025924       7 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt"
I0818 06:51:54.039912       7 status.go:214] "POD is not ready" pod="ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt" node="rpi3"
I0818 06:51:54.051540       7 status.go:299] "updating Ingress status" namespace="home-assistant" ingress="home-assistant-ingress" currentValue=[{IP:192.168.0.57 Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[]
I0818 06:51:54.071502       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"home-assistant", Name:"home-assistant-ingress", UID:"eeb12441-9cd4-4571-b0da-5b2978ff3267", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"14445", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0818 06:51:54.823911       7 controller.go:184] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0818 06:51:54.824200       7 controller.go:195] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0818 06:51:54.824334       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt", UID:"def1db3a-4766-4751-b611-ae3461911bc6", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"14423", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0818 06:51:57.788759       7 controller.go:1111] Service "home-assistant/home-assistant-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I0818 06:52:54.165805       7 status.go:299] "updating Ingress status" namespace="home-assistant" ingress="home-assistant-ingress" currentValue=[] newValue=[{IP:192.168.0.57 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0818 06:52:54.190556       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"home-assistant", Name:"home-assistant-ingress", UID:"eeb12441-9cd4-4571-b0da-5b2978ff3267", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"14590", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

Endpoints

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl get endpoints -A
NAMESPACE        NAME                                 ENDPOINTS                                     AGE
default          kubernetes                           192.168.0.53:6443                             35h
kube-system      kube-dns                             10.42.0.12:53,10.42.0.12:53,10.42.0.12:9153   35h
home-assistant   home-assistant-service               10.42.3.9:8123                                35h
kube-system      metrics-server                       10.42.0.14:4443                               35h
ingress-nginx    ingress-nginx-controller-admission   10.42.2.13:8443                               35h
ingress-nginx    ingress-nginx-controller             10.42.2.13:443,10.42.2.13:80                  35h
```

Can also confirm the Traefik Ingress controller is disabled

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE        NAME                                          READY   STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
ingress-nginx    ingress-nginx-admission-create-2thj7          0/1     Completed   0             22h
ingress-nginx    ingress-nginx-admission-patch-kwm4m           0/1     Completed   1             22h
kube-system      local-path-provisioner-7b7dc8d6f5-jcm4p       1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711-w88fv   1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      coredns-b96499967-rml6k                       1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711-rv8rf   1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711-9qk8m   1/1     Running     2 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      svclb-home-assistant-service-f2675711-m62sl   1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
home-assistant   home-assistant-deploy-7c4674b679-zbwn7        1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
kube-system      metrics-server-668d979685-rp2wm               1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   22h
ingress-nginx    ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-9h8wt     1/1     Running     2 (59m ago)   22h
```

Ingress Nginx Controller Service:

```
root@rpi1:~# kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx 
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.43.254.114   <none>        80:32313/TCP,443:31543/TCP   23h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.43.135.213   <none>        443/TCP                      23h
root@rpi1:~# kubectl describe svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.3.0
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.254.114
IPs:                      10.43.254.114
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32313/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.2.10:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31543/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.2.10:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Updated: added Ingress Nginx Controller service

Updated2: added Ingress Nginx Controller log and endpoints

Comment: What about the nginx controller service?

Comment: @Manuel sorry, just added it.